# JQL query to retrieve all events and filter by properites

Tags: mixpanel, jql

I am attempting to use the following query - the purpose of the query is to get all events and filter by property

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: "2018-01-01",
    to_date: "2018-03-30"
  }).filter(function(user) { return user.properties.account-type == "ecommerce" })
```

But getting this error:

```
Uncaught exception ReferenceError: type is not defined
  }).filter(function(properties) { return properties.account-type == "free" });
                                                         ^
```

Stack trace:
ReferenceError: type is not defined
    at :13:62

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the game on this one but you can use the `event_selector` argument in the `Events` object:

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: "2018-01-01",
    to_date: "2018-03-30",
    event_selector: [
        {event: "user", selector: '"ecommerce" in properties["account-type"]'}
    ]
  })
```

I'm assuming that `user` is the name of the event in this example.

source: https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/jql-api-reference

Answer (score -1):

Below code should work for you. Use the `properties.xyz` syntax only when the `xyz` does not have a special character else it will throw that error. In

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: "2018-01-01",
    to_date: "2018-03-30"
  }).filter(function(user) { return user.properties['account-type'] == "ecommerce" })
```